# private chat using shared objects in as3/flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

i am new to flex, i didn't have idea about private chat using shared objects in as3/flex.

any one can share their references or ideas regarding this..,

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

http://www.giantflyingsaucer.com/blog/?p=289
This seems like what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
    # This code is work as adding user to user list and allow the user's to private chat using #SharedObject.

    Client side code : 

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" height="500" width="700">
        <fx:Declarations>
            <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
        </fx:Declarations>
        <fx:Script>
            <![CDATA[
                import flash.events.AsyncErrorEvent;
                import flash.events.Event;
                import flash.events.MouseEvent;
                import flash.events.NetStatusEvent;
                import flash.events.SyncEvent;
                import flash.net.NetConnection;
                import flash.net.SharedObject;

                import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
                import mx.controls.Alert;
                import mx.events.FlexEvent;
                import mx.events.ListEvent;

                public var nc:NetConnection;
                private var so:SharedObject=null;
                public var tempUser:String;
                public var listUsr:String;
                private var soUser:String="users_so1";
                [Bindable]
                private var a:ArrayCollection;

                [Bindable]
                [Embed(source="src/online.png")]
                private var online:Class;

                [Bindable]
                [Embed(source="src/offline.png")]
                private var offline:Class;

                private var _alert:Alert;
                [Embed(source="src/online.png")]
                private var IconCritical:Class;

                private var uswerData:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection;

                protected function btnSubmit_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
                {
                    nc=new NetConnection();
                    nc.client=this;
                    nc.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS,netStatusHandler);
                    nc.connect("rtmp://localhost/test",txtUsername.text);
                    lblCurrentUser.text=txtUsername.text;
                }

                protected function  netStatusHandler(event:NetStatusEvent):void
                {
                    if (event.info.code == "NetConnection.Connect.Failed")
                    { 
                        trace(""+event.info.code);
                        Alert.show(""+event.info.code);
                    }

                    else if (event.info.code == "NetConnection.Connect.Rejected")
                    { 
                        trace(""+event.info.code);
                        Alert.show(""+event.info.code);
                    }

                    else(event.info.code == "NetConnection.Connect.Success") 
                    {
                        trace(""+event.info.code);
                        SharedObject.defaultObjectEncoding=flash.net.ObjectEncoding.AMF3;
                        so=SharedObject.getRemote(soUser,nc.uri,false);
                        so.addEventListener(SyncEvent.SYNC,syncEvent);
                        so.connect(nc);
                        so.client=this;
                    }
                }

                protected function syncEvent(event:SyncEvent):void{
                    a=new ArrayCollection();
                    for (var prop:String in so.data) 
                    { 
                        var obj:Object = new Object;
                        obj.name = prop;
                        obj.status=so.data[prop];
                        a.addItem(obj);                     
                    }
                    lstOnlineUsers.dataProvider=a;
                    lstOnlineUsers.addEventListener(MouseEvent.DOUBLE_CLICK,onDoubleClick);
                }

                protected function findIcon(item:Object):String {
                    if(item.status == "hold") {
                        //lstOnlineUsers.setStyle("icon",online);
                        item.icon = online;
                        //item.name=item.name;
                        return item.name;
                    }
                    else {
                        //lstOnlineUsers.setStyle("icon",offline);
                        item.icon = offline;
                        //item.name=item.name;
                        return item.name;
                    }
                }

                protected function onDoubleClick(e:MouseEvent):void{

                    listUsr=""+lstOnlineUsers.selectedItem.name;
                    lblReceiverName.text=listUsr;
                }

                private function eSendClick(event:Event):void
                {
                    sendMessage();
                }

                public function sendMessage():void{

                    var obj:Object=new Object();
                    obj.sender=lblCurrentUser.text;
                    obj.msg=txtMessage.text;
                    obj.receiver=lblReceiverName.text;
                    so.send("showMessage",obj);
                }

                public function showMessage(msg:Object):void{
                    if(msg.sender==lblCurrentUser.text){
                    if(msg.sender==msg.receiver || lblReceiverName.text=="UserNotSelected")
                    {
                        Alert.show("Select A Receiver !");
                        return;
                    }
                }
// you can comment this below condition statement this will work as public chat

                    if((msg.receiver==lblCurrentUser.text) || (msg.sender==lblCurrentUser.text) ){
                        txtDisplay.text += msg.sender+" : "+msg.msg+ "\n";
                        txtMessage.text = "";

                        if(msg.receiver==lblCurrentUser.text)
                            showAlert(msg.sender);
                    }
                }

                private function showAlert(sender:String):void{

                    var myMessage:String = "!!!";
                    var myTitle:String = "Messagesg Received From "+sender;
                    _alert = Alert.show(myMessage, myTitle, Alert.OK, null, null, IconCritical);
                }

                private function onErrorMsg(event:AsyncErrorEvent):void{
                    trace("========================= onErrorMsg"+"\r");
                }

            ]]>
        </fx:Script>


        <!--design-->
        <s:Panel x="97" y="78" width="239" height="337"
                 title="Welcome User" id="panelUsers">
            <s:Label id="lblCurrentUser" x="103" y="-22" width="89" height="16"
                     text=""/>
            <s:Label id="lblUser" x="30" y="47" width="78" height="30" text="Username"
                     verticalAlign="middle"/>
            <s:TextInput id="txtUsername" width="86" height="29" 
                         horizontalCenter="-44" verticalCenter="-68" />
            <!--<s:TextInput id="txtPassword" width="88" height="21" horizontalCenter="-50" verticalCenter="-8" />-->   
            <s:Button id="btnSubmit" x="126" y="76" label="Submit" click="btnSubmit_clickHandler(event)"/>
            <mx:List id="lstOnlineUsers" x="26" y="117" width="138" height="174" 
                     labelFunction="findIcon" doubleClickEnabled="true" />
        </s:Panel>
        <s:Panel x="381" y="92" width="250" height="308"
                 id="panelChat" title="To: ">
            <s:TextArea x="20" y="9" width="207" height="196" id="txtDisplay" editable="false"/>
            <s:TextInput x="20" y="215" width="140" id="txtMessage"/>
            <s:Button x="168" y="216" label="SEND" id="btnSend" click="sendMessage()"/>
            <s:Label x="31" y="-22" id="lblReceiverName" text="UserNotSelected"/>

        </s:Panel>
        <!--design-->
    </s:WindowedApplication>

    ------------------------
    server side code :
    ------------------------
    application.onAppStart = function()
    {
        trace("Begin....");

        // Get the server shared object 'users_so'
        application.users_so = SharedObject.get("users_so1", false);
    }

    application.onConnect = function(client, name)
    {
        //trace("clients::"+application.clients.length)
        var temp = application.users_so.getProperty(name);
        if (temp)
        {
            application.rejectConnection(client);
            return false;
        }
        client.name = name;
        application.users_so.setProperty(name,"hold");
        application.acceptConnection(client);
    }


    application.onDisconnect = function(client)
    {
        trace("disconnect: " + client.name);
        application.users_so.setProperty(client.name, null);
        //users_so1.clear();
    }
```

Comment: This code is used for private chat application with adding user list using shared object in as3 with minimal designs... this might be used for new as3 developers.